# How to solve a "symbol dyld_stub_binder not found" error

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker-errors, dylib, dyld

I'm having problem building and running my app cause after an error message told me some plugin was missing. I googled the message and tried to add some files to my project (not longer sure what I did, just followed instruction). I then got like 15 warnings, so I undid it, but the app still doesn't run. The first warning says:

> ld: warning: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found, normally in
>   libSystem.dylib Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

I've tried to find a solution and I've seen a couple of topics that is close to this one, but not the same. I reinstalled Xcode, and still no luck. I've tried some other projects and they are working so something has happened to my project.

I also get all kind of error messages, like:

> "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BokbynAppDelegate in BokbynAppDelegate.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_BokbynAppDelegate in BokbynAppDelegate.o
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FirstViewController in FirstViewController.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FirstViewController in FirstViewController.o
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AddresAnnotation in FirstViewController.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_AddresAnnotation in FirstViewController.o
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SecondViewController in SecondViewController.o  "

Answer (score 1):

change your Deployment Target to 4.0+

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly give us more background on what kind of project it is? From the looks of it you were correct in thinking that you are missing a framework as that is what tends to cause the linker errors. Without seeing any code I couldn't tell you what framework you might be missing though.

Additionally, the warnings shouldn't scare you, start with the first one and go through trying to fix them. It is very possible that your code will generate warnings when you  figure out your missing framework.

What language are you writing this in? Are you using xcode to compile C or are you staying with Objective-C?

Comment: Hi! I've solved it. For some reason I got a weird search path for the library, but everything works fine now after deleting that path. Thanks anyway :)